# I can't show my custom Button on android emulator

Tags: react-native

I take a tutorial that show a button succeed , but my button show like a line in the same code . Why ? The reason is my emulator is Android not IOS ?

Here is my custom Button setting:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Button = ({ onPress, children }) => {

    const { buttonStyle, textStyle } = styles;

    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
            <Text style={textStyle}>
                {children}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
};

const styles = {
    textStyle: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        color: '#007aff',
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: '600',
        paddingTop: 10,
        paddingBottom: 10
    },
    buttonStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        alignSelf: 'stretch',
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#007aff',
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5
    },
};
export { Button };
```

Here is i call the Button:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { Header, Button } from './components/common';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';


class App extends Component {
    state = { loggedIn: false };

    componentWillMount() {
        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: "AIzaSyAW3A_RYT0Hn73j-HjpFBzAV4lrJnsUATI",
            authDomain: "auth-4ff37.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://auth-4ff37.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "auth-4ff37",
            storageBucket: "auth-4ff37.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "524723794907"
        });

        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            if (user) {
                this.setState({ loggedIn: true });
            } else {
                this.setState({ loggedIn: false })
            }
        });
    }

    renderContent() {
        if (this.state.loggedIn) {
            return (
                // It show a blue line not a button
                <Button>
                    Log out
                </Button>
            );
        }

        return <LoginForm />;
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Header headerText="App title bar" />
                {this.renderContent()}
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my file root:
[image]

Should i have some special setting for Android ?

Any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance.

left photo is `return <LoginForm />;` right photo is `return (
                <Button>
                    Log out
                    </Button>
            );`
[image]

Comment: Any screenshot of how your button look now ? And is your header showing up correctly ?

Comment: Sure , i upload the photo , i use the same custom button , right is uncorrect .

Comment: Can you try adding marginTop : 50 in that buttonStyle ?  I am guessing there must be something wrong with styling . May be just look into LoginForm container style and compare with Button container style.  Should comeup with something

Comment: I try to use marginTop: 50 , it still show a blue line , but i take your advice compare the setting again  , i try to use the same layout like the left photo that have a CardSection outside . Finally i see a button succeed .

But the tutorial just only use a `<Button>` although he run on IOS emulator , it so confused with me .   Any way thanks for your help , you help me the point .

Comment: Glad that it help :)